# Why does adding lazy loading to a React Vite project result in an empty root node?

Tags: reactjs, vite, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

I am developing an app using React (Typescript) and Vite. To reduce bundle size, I want to implement code splitting, using React's [lazy](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy) function. I am keen not to introduce a 3rd party library for this.

But when I run the app, all I see is a blank page, and devtools reveals that the App component has not been added under the root node:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
</body>
```

What am I missing here?

---

So we initialise a new project using `npm create vite@latest` and remove some of the boilerplate.

We create a really basic component `MyComponent`:

```js
// MyComponent.tsx
const MyComponent = () => {
  return <p>component text</p>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

and lazily import it into `App.tsx`

```js
// App.tsx
import { lazy } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const MyComponent = lazy(() => import("./MyComponent"));
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My page</h1>
      <MyComponent />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But when we run the app, all we see is a blank page, and devtools reveals that the App component has not been added under the root node.

[a blank webpage in chrome with the devtools inspector open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmRLu.png)

[Link to a repo containing a minimal example](https://github.com/pmarsh-scottlogic/ReactViteLazyLoadingExample)

I am at a loss of what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [React docs](https://fr.react.dev/reference/react/lazy#troubleshooting) specifies that you have to declare the lazy import components outside of the scope of a component.

You have to import them just like you would for regular imports: at the top of your `tsx` file

```
// App.tsx
import { lazy } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const MyComponent = lazy(() => import("./MyComponent"));

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My page</h1>
      <MyComponent />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```